# Bank Vocabulary regarding Cheque

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, formal-language

Some banks in USA, send a cheque to the payee and then deduct the amount when the payee presents the cheque to their bank . As the transaction is processed the money is deducted from the payer's account.

Some other banks , deduct the money as the cheque is issued . Some banks call it a banker's check (USA).

What is the name of the former ?
Are there any alternate names for such transactions ?

Comment: It's a [personal cheque](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/personal-cheque). (In the US, it can also be spelled *personal check*).

Answer (score 1):

We usually just call the first kind "a check".  A check is technically a kind of *draft*, which is an order from one party (the payer) to another (the bank) to release funds to a third party (the payee).  But nobody calls it "a draft" in normal speech; that's strictly financial jargon.  (And a draft is a kind of *financial instrument*.)

The *bank check* or *cashier's check* is just a check written by the bank against its own funds.  They deduct the money from your account when you get one because then they put that into their account, against which the check is written.

References:

- [Uniform Commercial Code, § 3-104. NEGOTIABLE INSTRUMENT](https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/3/3-104)
- [Kinds of Bank Checks](http://www.legalmatch.com/law-library/article/kinds-of-bank-checks.html)